# Mongoose: Nested findById returns null

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to do a nested `findById` call to get a child record. The inner `findById` keeps returning `null` even though there is a Thread with an `_id` matching the `post.thread` property on the doc returned by the outer `findById` call. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Here are my schemas:

```
PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    message: { type: String },
    thread: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }
});

ThreadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    title: String,
    pageCount: Number,
    thingsTheySaid: Array,
    lastScraped: Date
});
```

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
Post.findById(req.params.post).lean().exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    Thread.findById(post.thread).lean().exec(function (err, thread) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, err);
        // thread is always null here, instead of the expected lean object
        if (!thread) return res.send(500, 'thread not found');
        post.thread = thread;

        res.render('posts/edit', post);
    });
});
```

Here's the data as shown in the mongo CLI:

```
// post
{ 
    "title" : "C1", 
    "thread" : ObjectId("5154b8bc741aa70000000001"), 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5154b8bf741aa70000000002"), 
    "__v" : 0 
}

// thread
{ 
    "lastScraped" : ISODate("2013-03-28T21:23:22.750Z"), 
    "pageCount" : 15, 
    "title" : "GDT: Game #25 : Kings @ Coyotes - Tuesday,  3/12/�13 @ 7:00 pm PDT - HFBoards", 
    "url" : "http://hfboards.hockeysfuture.com/showthread.php?t=1373783", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5154b4cae60b210000000001"), 
    "thingsTheySaid" : [ /*snipped for Brevity*/ ]
}
```

**Solution Using `populate()`**

nevi_me was on the right track using the `populate()` function, but this is the code I ended up using to solve the problem.

```
PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    message: { type: String },
    thread: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Thread', required: true }
});

Post.findById(req.params.post).populate('thread').exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    res.render('posts/edit', post);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to just run a `populate()` in your query.
`populate` will take the `ObjectId` and attach its corresponding document to your `post`. Try change to the following

**Schema**

```
PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    message: { type: String },
    thread: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Thread', required: true }
});
```

**findById**

```
Post.findById(req.params.post).populate('thread').exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    res.render('posts/edit', post);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code didn't work for me, but populate() did the trick so I'm giving you credit for the answer.

Comment: @CraigM I didn't expect the structure og the post document to be exactly the same, hence I said that you might need to tweak it. 
You may update my answer with what you did so that in future someone else gets the right answer too.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Nevi. It wasn't the schemas that was the problem. It's that the populate method is not on the Mongoose Model object (Post in my example). It's on the Document object. populate was the key to fixing my problem though. I've updated your answer. Thanks again.